# I am trying to perform a vlookup on data below an empty row I inserted

Tags: excel, vba

I have inserted a blank row between my data to separate it and I am trying to perform a vlookup from the bottom half of the data. As I change it, I get an error or sometimes it does a vlookup on the top half of the data but I only want it to do from my inserted row down. Right now, the bottom half starts at A601 but will change from week to week. What code can perform what I am trying to accomplish?

```
Sub Test
     Dim z As Long
     Dim k As Long
     z = Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     k = Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row
     Range(“C4:C” & z).Formula =“=Vlookup(A4,’[Emp.txt]Emp’!$A:$C” & k & “,3,False)”
End sub
```

Comment: `k = Range(“A1").End(xlDown).row` & `Range("C" & K +2 & ":C" & z).Formula`

Comment: Would my Formula I have above work with what you put?

Comment: As I replaced what k equals to what you put, it still gave me an error. Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: Remove the `” & k & “` from the formula

Comment: This is giving me a “type mismatch error”. How would I go about fixing this error?

Comment: It is giving me the error on k = Range(“A1”).End(xlDown).row & Range(“C” & k +2 & “:C” & z)

Comment: Those were two different lines not one: `k = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row`  and `Range("C" & k +2 & ":C" & z).Formula = "=Vlookup(A4,'[Emp.txt]Emp'!$A:$C,3,False)"`